# How to select level of detalization of point cloud(xyz points)

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

What opengl parameters i must use for LOD selection?

I use glortho

```
glOrtho(boxC.x-maxLen/1 - dL, boxC.x + maxLen/1 + dL, boxC.y-maxLen/1 - dL, boxC.y + maxLen/1 + dL, -(f_scale)*max_z, f_scale*max_z);
```

Comment: OpenGL doesn't have LOD for points. Only textures have LOD (called mipmaps)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. OpenGL has no feature called LOD.

If you want to render less points when the camera is a certain distance away, it is up to your program to do that. Unless you just want to ignore points that are farther than a certain distance away - the far clipping plane (the last parameter to `glOrtho`) controls the maximum distance at which things can be displayed.